# Since ERC token names, symbols cannot be reserved, anyone recommend selfdestruct/suicide method call?

Tags: tokens, selfdestruct

As we know contracts are unique ..  has anyone 'reserved' a token name/ symbol before final deployment, by putting a suicide by owner method.. so this dummy can be 'removed' just before the same token name and symbol is then deployed to take its place.

Will a contract suicide (selfdestruct method call) 'remove' any reference from etherscan, I am sure it will as that contract will be nullified ? by that call.

how does the chain 'remove' or just blank out the Hash of the now suicided contract

thanks

Answer (score 1):

Contracts are unique by address, but any number of contracts can be deployed with the same exact code (which includes token name/symbol). Token name and symbol can also be changed if you code your contract to have a way to update them.

A selfdestructed contract will not remove all history of the contract from etherscan, but it does say that it was selfdestructed.

Similarly, a selfdestructed contract doesn't actually get deleted from the chains history, as that would make it mutable. It simply removes it from the state tree so that transactions to it don't trigger the contract code.

Comment: Thanks Flygoing.. do you know much about version control of SCs for industrial use-cases.. it seems only selfdestruct upon user agreement for the new logic and new SC deploy is the only way.. its the nature of the data struct, yep